# Python multiprocessing Queue NotImplementedError macOS

Tags: python, macos, python-multiprocessing

**System information**

- python 3.8.7
- OS 11.1 (Big Sur)
- Python installed via `brew install python@3.8`

To reproduce on Big Sur and most probably older versions:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exp_queue = mp.Queue()
    print(exp_queue.qsize())
```

**Results in:**

```
  File "/Users/username/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(exp_queue.qsize())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 120, in qsize
    return self._maxsize - self._sem._semlock._get_value()
NotImplementedError
```

It looks like whoever wrote this in `multiprocessing/queues.py line 120` is aware of the issue, but I can't find a solution somewhere:

```
def qsize(self):
    # Raises NotImplementedError on Mac OSX because of broken sem_getvalue()
    return self._maxsize - self._sem._semlock._get_value()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

**Simplest solution**: use [multiprocessing.Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Manager). It provides a `Queue` class with `qsize()` implemented. You don't have to copypasta GPL-licensed code. Quick example:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker(x, que):
    que.put(x**2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = list(range(1000))

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
    m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = m.Queue()
    workers = [pool.apply_async(worker, (i, q)) for i in inputs]
    while q.qsize() < len(inputs):
        time.sleep(1)

    results = [q.get() for _ in range(q.qsize())]
    assert len(results) == len(inputs)
```

I'm running Ventura 13.0.1 (macOS) and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

As Víctor Terrón has suggested in a GitHub discussion, you can use his implementation:

https://github.com/vterron/lemon/blob/d60576bec2ad5d1d5043bcb3111dff1fcb58a8d6/methods.py#L536-L573

According to the doc:

> A portable implementation of multiprocessing.Queue.
> Because of multithreading / multiprocessing semantics, Queue.qsize() may
> raise the NotImplementedError exception on Unix platforms like Mac OS X
> where sem_getvalue() is not implemented. This subclass addresses this
> problem by using a synchronized shared counter (initialized to zero) and
> increasing / decreasing its value every time the put() and get() methods
> are called, respectively. This not only prevents NotImplementedError from
> being raised, but also allows us to implement a reliable version of both
> qsize() and empty().

Comment: To anyone finding this, be aware that Víctor Terrón's Queue implementation is licensed under the GPL, meaning that you can't use it in your code without also making your code GPL licensed.