# How to get `multiprocessing.queues.Queue.qsize()` on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, multiprocessing, queue

This is an old [issue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20this%20may%20raise%20NotImplementedError%20on%20Unix%20platforms%20like%20macOS%20where%20sem_getvalue()%20is%20not%20implemented.) which suggested [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65609529/python-multiprocessing-queue-notimplementederror-macos) does not work.

Below is a complete example showing how the suggested approach fails. Uncomment L31 for error.

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import get_context
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue


class SharedCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, n=0):
        self.count = multiprocessing.Value('i', n)

    def increment(self, n=1):
        with self.count.get_lock():
            self.count.value += n

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.count.value


class MyQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyQueue, self).__init__(*args, ctx=get_context(), **kwargs)
        self.size = SharedCounter(0)

    def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.size.increment(1)
        super(MyQueue, self).put(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.size.increment(-1)  # uncomment this for error
        return super(MyQueue, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    def qsize(self):
        return self.size.value

    def empty(self):
        return not self.qsize()

    def clear(self):
        while not self.empty():
            self.get()


def worker(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        print(f'[{os.getpid()}]: got {item}')
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_processes = 4
    q = MyQueue()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processes, worker, (q,))

    for i in range(10):
        q.put("hello")
        q.put("world")

    for i in range(num_processes):
        q.put(None)

    q.close()
    q.join_thread()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

For some reason, the newly defined `MyQueue` forgets about the `size` attribute.

```
Process SpawnPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 109, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 47, in worker
    item = queue.get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 31, in get
    self.size.increment(-1)  # uncomment this for error
    ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MyQueue' object has no attribute 'size'
Process SpawnPoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 109, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 47, in worker
    item = queue.get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 31, in get
    self.size.increment(-1)  # uncomment this for error
    ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MyQueue' object has no attribute 'size'
Process SpawnPoolWorker-4:
Process SpawnPoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 109, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 47, in worker
    item = queue.get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 31, in get
    self.size.increment(-1)  # uncomment this for error
    ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MyQueue' object has no attribute 'size'
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 109, in worker
    initializer(*initargs)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 47, in worker
    item = queue.get()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/scratches/scratch.py", line 31, in get
    self.size.increment(-1)  # uncomment this for error
    ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'MyQueue' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you didn't to override `__setstate__` and `__getstate__` to include your variable, which are used by pickle to control the serialization [Handling Stateful Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects) ... so you should override them to add your variable to what's being serialized.

```py
import multiprocessing
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import get_context
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue

class SharedCounter(object):
    def __init__(self, n=0):
        self.count = multiprocessing.Value('i', n)

    def increment(self, n=1):
        with self.count.get_lock():
            self.count.value += n

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.count.value

class MyQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyQueue, self).__init__(*args, ctx=get_context(), **kwargs)
        self.size = SharedCounter(0)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return (super(MyQueue, self).__getstate__(),self.size)
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        super(MyQueue, self).__setstate__(state[0])
        self.size = state[1]
    
    def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.size.increment(1)
        super(MyQueue, self).put(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.size.increment(-1)  # uncomment this for error
        return super(MyQueue, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    def qsize(self):
        return self.size.value

    def empty(self):
        return not self.qsize()

    def clear(self):
        while not self.empty():
            self.get()

def worker(queue):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        print(f'[{os.getpid()}]: got {item}')
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_processes = 4
    q = MyQueue()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_processes, initializer=worker, initargs=(q,))

    for i in range(10):
        q.put("hello")
        q.put("world")

    for i in range(num_processes):
        q.put(None)

    q.close()
    q.join_thread()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

note that in python 3 we don't need to use `super(MyQueue, self)`, as `super()` would suffice, and will make it easier to rename your class in the future and other portability and refactoring benefits, so consider swapping any `super(x,y)` with just `super()`

Comment: This works but why does it generate a warning in PyCharm stating `Unresolved attribute reference '__getstate__' for class 'Queue' `? and the same for `__setstate__`